# The meaning of "n_jobs == 1" in GridSearchCV with using multiple GPU

Tags: scikit-learn, keras

I have been training NN model by using Keras framework with 4 NVIDIA GPU. (Data Row Count: ~160,000, Column Count: 5). Now I want to optimize its parameter by using GridSearchCV.

However, I encountered several different errors whenever I tried to change n_jobs to other values than one. Error, such as

```
CUDA OUT OF MEMORY
Can not get device properties error code : 3
```

Then I read this web page,
"# if you're not using a GPU, you can set n_jobs to something other than 1"
http://queirozf.com/entries/scikit-learn-pipeline-examples

So it is not possible to use multiple GPU with GridSearchCV?

[Environment]
Ubuntu 16.04
Python 3.6.0
Keras / Scikit-Learn

Thanks!

Comment: What backend are you using for Keras?

Comment: After @MarcusV. comment, can you please add the code you're using (specifically the one includes the imports and the `GridSearch` part

Answer (score 7):

According to the FAQ in scikit learn - GPU is NOT supported. [Link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#will-you-add-gpu-support)

You can use `n_jobs` to use your CPU cores. If you want to run at maximum speed you might want to use *almost* all your cores:

```
import multiprocessing
n_jobs = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1
```

Comment: He's using Keras though (with sklearn wrapper, I suppose), so GPU are supported (if the backend supports it).

Comment: Will using all the cores hang the execution of other processes?
Could you elaborate why using all cores but one is better?

Comment: Using all cores will slow down everything else going in your computer (It even might not be optimized for your "program", but I'm not sure of that claim). Try it.